# callback with optional 2nd argument

Tags: typescript, overloading

**Issue**

I just want a simple function that accepts callback with 1 or 2 arguments.

1. If only 1 argument callback is passed that function will br called automatically the non-exist 2nd argument created internally inside the function.
2. If 2 arguments callback is passed that function will not be called the 2nd argument. You have to call it inside the callback.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQlC8UAUBKBA%20KA3A9gSwBMBuAWAChy8A7YCAJwDMBDAY2gGEmAbLgI1YDWUAN7koyJgC4oVAK4BbXvRTTchUmXFIpMhUroAaKL2kwV2fMTETpcxfSO8A-KfNqrZAL7lyDWVRZgPBwqKFoAZ2AkFm4%20QWlOHn4WATdLDT8AoJCwiEjo2OSBBMLBNPVff0Dg0IiomKT4qES4lPKCEWsWEMioJgQoAEYNcW6qXt4B1AwoMfCcLggAOi4cAHMkAHIACwgeHE2UDWs8BmQG1oEViCo14G2EeERBtFFNcVnSlO0jn3fxXioIhQAD0IM%20PGoaygACJeDCoAQ8HQIIEuCBrN4KO9TucvldFrd7o9EAAmV7WUb47SOX7vLFY8hgj5QAA%20AFp2ayoABRABKfIA8nzyHUkDTjGh4Jg3qMegtlqsNkw6dZAXTPEcgA)

---

**Error**

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.

Overload 1 of 2, '(callback: Callback): void', gave the following error.   
Argument of type '(a: any, b: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Callback'. 

Overload 2 of 2, '(callback: Callback): void', gave the following error.
Argument of type '(a: any, b: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Callback'.
```

---

**Code**

```ts
type B = () => void;

interface Callback {
  (a: number): void;
  (a: number, b: B): void;
  (a: number, b?: B): void;
}

function test(callback: Callback): void;
function test(callback: Callback): void;
function test(callback: Callback): void {
  const a = 1;
  const b = () => console.log('hello');

  if (callback.length === 1) {
    callback(a);

    b(); // calling "b" directly
  }

  if (callback.length === 2) {
    callback(a, b);
  }
}

//    |--| ERROR
test((a, b) => {
  console.log(a);

  b();
});
```

Comment: Because than it will throw an error inside callback: "TS2722: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'."

Comment: Why not just always pass both arguments? Like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQlC8UAUBKBA+KA3A9gSwBMBuAWAChy8A7YCAJwDMBDAY2gGEmAbLgI1YDWUAN7koyJgC4oVAK4BbXvQA0UXtJgppuQqTIBfcuQayqLYHhxUotAM7AkLbn0HTOPfiwFbs+AiLEoLghgKAIraERmLlsIPXEWK3soJgQoAEZ4qESqZN401AwAsnFxcKpImzpZOMCEpJxggDouHABzJAByAAsIHhxOlCz9PUCnD0EkJlVeIaMSqDwGZABCcog0UQXxXlRh8kMKMjsHKZm0eEwt+tzGiBb2qbmjnb2D5-ITpCei6+yG5qtDpMZ76Z5AA).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all those overloads

```js
type B = () => void;

interface Callback {
  (a: number, b?: B): void;
}

function test(callback: Callback): void {
    const a = 1;
    const b = () => console.log('hello');

    switch (callback.length) {
        case 1: callback(a); b(); break;
        case 2: callback(a, b); break;
    }
}

test((a, b) => {
  console.log(a);
  
  if (typeof b === "function") {
    b()
  }
});

test((a) => { console.log(a); });
```

[Example on the TS Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAQlC8UAUBKBA+KA3A9gSwBMBuAKBLwDtgIAnAMwEMBjaAYQYBsOAjZgaygBvElGQMAXFAoBXALbdaAGijcA-JJgpJuQqVEBfMnWkUmwPDgpRqAZ2BImnHv0nsuvJny3Z8BISKgmSzsoBgQoAEY9QODgFXDUDBiKGxwOCAA6DhwAcyQAcgALCC4cfJRSAJsAdzxgJkLkR3d+LIgKHOBCtGFRUUcbaAjJZudPJAYKlVQiFRoIBj5o-oZBqAAmEacPPgnlbinuecXow0MSW3s9lTR4TF7k1PSs3ImKslE8OmRQSBxv7gIeCIABExlM5ksIJ6AVE3FQATO7wuEDsSDeSUEjzSmWyeUms30FSAA)

Comment: You know that `console.log` accepts `undefined` value... but try invoke function like that: `b();` and It throws error *Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.*

Comment: You "console.log" value of "b" which is "() => void | undefined" (of course no-typescript error) but you can not call "undefined"... I mean that "b" can not be "undefined"

Comment: @Altaula Added a `b()` call in the first "callback"